# Facebook like button not following through with like

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I've just created a "splash page" of sorts for our Wifi where I would like the user to like our facebook page first.
I've included the button and it shows up, The user can click the like button and proceed to where it asks you to log in and then the page where it asks if you would like to like the page.
However testing this, when I click the "confirm" button it's not registering that I've like the page.

I've double checked that my app page is public and that the ID is correct.
Gone through the facebook page where it instructs you on what to do but still no dice.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<img src="images/background.jpg" alt="" class="responsive" width="1080" height="1080"><br>
<h1>1. LIKE OUR FACEBOOK PAGE</h1>
<div id="step1" class="center"><tr>
    <td>
        <img style="text-align: center;" alt="arrow" class="imgResponsive" src="images/leftarrow.png"/></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 100px">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/[hidden]" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img style="text-align: center;" alt="arrow" class="imgResponsive" src="images/arrow.png"/>
    </td>
</tr></div>
```

This is pretty much the whole page minus unimportant details.
Basically, I just need it to register **the like**.

Comment: This is kind of hard for us to reproduce.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that. But I thought maybe I'm missing something that someone would be able to point out.

Comment: Anything I could add to be more helpful?

Comment: You are not allowed to “force” the user to give a like to begin with. If you want something like this, you should not build it yourself in the first place, but use https://www.facebook.com/business/facebook-wifi instead. (And even there the like is optional.)

Comment: They're not forced, they can click a button and jump straight on the wifi, which we're sponsoring. We'd just like to make it easy to be liked but it won't register the like.

Comment: in addition to what @04FS said: i guess it´s because you are trying to use a like button BEFORE the user connected to the wifi. there´s no internet. no possibility to like something. on the other hand, it´s weird that the like button even shows up, because you would even need internet for that...anyway, maybe that helps.

Comment: Cheers for your input @luschn but we have the walled garden whitelist in place, which allows the button to show, as you said.

Comment: just the button? are you sure you´ve whitelisted everything facebook needs, for the like? what happens if you test with existing internet connection? does it work then?

Comment: Really should've mentioned that earlier, sorry. Yes I have tried on the normal wifi.

Comment: Update: I've tried using my partners note 5 on chrome and browsed to the webserver on her phone from our home wifi, the like button worked perfectly. Doing the same thing on the same network on my phone s8+ default internet browser and it will not register. Is this an OS or browser compatibility thing?